self inside Lua constructors
Sorry it's not quite a specific question.
In the "Programming in Lua, 4th edition" one can see the following code :
Account = {balance = 0}

function Account:new (o)
    o = o or {}
    self.__index = self
    setmetatable(o, self)
    return o
end

My confusion is the line
self.__index = self

This means that Account becomes its own __index only on creation of an instance :
a = Account:new()

which is confusing if you think about it. I know that it is done to easily increase the depth of inheritance so you can do :
AccountGold = Account:new({cashBackPercentage = 5})
AccountPlatinum = AccountGold:new({personalSupport = true})

but to me this
Account.__index = Account

looks more readable.
Even more confusing. For example, look at the yui library:
local Button = setmetatable({
    __call = function(cls, args) return cls:new(args) end
}, Widget)
Button.__index = Button


function Button:new(args)
    self = setmetatable(args, self)

    self.text = self.text or ""
    self.align = self.align or 'center'
    self.valign = self.valign or 'center'
    self.active = false
    if not self.notranslate then
        self.text = T(self.text)
    end
    return self
end


Look at this :
self = setmetatable(args, self)

which reads to :
Button = setmetatable(args, Button)

which means that every time new instance is created the Button table is changed.
Is it like a common practice ? Could you comment on this please ?

Those who votes for closing -- could you please tell why as I can't see the reasons you've chosen.

What you read is incorrect, self = setmetatable(args, self) doesn't change Button, it just overwrites the parameter self to the return value of setmetatable, so it is equivalent to the following code:
local t = setmetatable(args, self)
t.text = t.text or ""
...

The implicit parameter self is dynamic, its value depends on how the function is invoked. For Account:new(....), self is Account, for AccountGold:new(....), self is AccountGold, so that you can achieve inheritance with a single function.
self.__index = self is cheap, but if you need to strictly control the exposed members, you should create a separate metatable.

"The implicit parameter self is dynamic, its value depends on how the function is invoked." -- I know this. More over second paragraph of your answer is already in the original post. When you write b = Button:new() self is Button so the resulting line is Button = setmetatable(...), isn't it ?

No, the resulting line is local t = setmetatable(args, Button)

@LRDPRDX self is the variable, which contains the same table value as Button. So self = setmetatable(args, self) changes the value of self from being equivalent to Button to being equivalent to args.

shingo's second paragraph is emphasizing that Account.__index = Account is not simply a difference in "readability", but changes the meaning of the code. It destroys the dynamic prototype chain, i.e., setmetatable(o, self) relies on self.__index = self to set up proper prototypical indexing.

Yeah, I got it now. Still think it can lead to undesired behaviour unless it is the first statement. F.e. if one does self.x = 'foo' before doing self = .... Ok. Thank you for your answers !

@Oka, "An instance of AccountGold loses access to methods defined through AccountGold" -- yes, I understand that. Of course you can then "override" the AccountGold's new in order it to work.
